# uib-dropdown not working in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a simple dropdown navigation to a navbar using the uib-dropdown directive but all I can get is the dropdown list showing up under the main navigation. There are no examples in the docs for this type of implementation but it seems like it should be pretty simple.

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JDBSgODfxS46mCzUPHlb?p=preview) showing the behavior and my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">angular-gmap-gplace</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li class="active" uib-dropdown>
        <a id="dDrop" uib-dropdown-toggle>Directive<span class="caret"></span></a>                                         
        <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="dDrop">
          <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#">Multiple</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to include an ng-app attribute as well as add the ui.bootstrap module to the app module. i forked your plunker and made a small change in the script.js file. I also added the ng-app attribute to the index.html
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kWTvnZzEFKONnGAIzj1t?p=preview)

```
 <body ng-app='app'>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">angular-gmap-gplace</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li class="active" uib-dropdown>
        <a id="dDrop" uib-dropdown-toggle>Directive                                          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="dDrop">
          <li role="menuitem">
            <a href="#">Multiple</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<h1>uib-dropdown in navbar</h1>
```

```
script.js
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']);
```